# parse xml jquery and repeat a check

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, loops, repeat

current code

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://xSSHplusx.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/livestatus.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {


        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
            $xml = $(xmlDoc);

    if($xml.find('ls:isLive').text()=='true'){
         player.load('SSHplus');
         }
         else{
            player.load('SaveStateHeroes');
           }
    }
});
```

I need to figure out a way to repeat this check every few seconds to get updates from the XML output to actually test when the status changes from false to true

Comment: would get more response if you were more specific what you are trying to `figure out`

Comment: I need to loop this code every 5~ seconds to check when the xml changes to change the player "channel", but I can't seem to make it continuously loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it with a time-out after the `ajax` call succeeded either with success or with error. This construction makes sure that you will not make the call before the previous has finished (network congestion).

```
function doYourThing() {
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://xSSHplusx.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/livestatus.xml",
     dataType: "xml",
     success: function (xml) {
       var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
       $xml = $(xmlDoc);

       if($xml.find('ls:isLive').text()=='true'){
         player.load('SSHplus');
       } else{
         player.load('SaveStateHeroes');
       }

       setTimeout(function() {
          doYourThing();
       }, 2000); /* timeout in ms */

    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var intervalId = window.setInterval(function() {
  // insert the code you wrote
  },
  5000 // or whatever number of milliseconds counts as "a few"
);
```

When you want to stop checking:

```
window.clearInterval(intervalId);
```